# Ant: How to select the latest modified file from a directory?

Tags: ant

Assume I have a directory which contains several files with the same name prefix and a timestamp, e.g.

```
my-directory:
- file-0749
- file-1253
- file-2304
```

How can I tell ANT to select the latest modified file from my directory (in this case this would be file-2304)?

Comment: This answer does it without using ant-contrib: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154641/ant-copy-newest-file-with-file-name-filter

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do that with the [`TimestampSelector`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/timestampselector.html) task from [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/).

```
<timestampselector property="latest.modified">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="${my-directory.dir}">
      <include name="file-*" />
    </fileset>
  </path>
</timestampselector>

<echo message="${latest.modified}" />
```

Comment: Great thanks for your hint! I didn't know about the <timestampselector>. With this task it is really easy to solve :-)

Comment: how can i copy the latest modified file or folder to different directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way without an additional library:

```
<copy todir="${tmp.last.modified.dir}">
    <last id="last.modified">
        <sort>
            <date />
            <fileset dir="${my.dir}" />
        </sort>
    </last>
</copy>
<echo message="last modified file in ${my.dir}: ${ant.refid:last.modified}" />
```

You can work directly with `ant.refid:last.modified` like the echo task does. Don't forget to delete `tmp.last.modified.dir`.