# ant copy copying order

Tags: ant, build-automation

I am new to ant  and  i want to know how the ant copy  decides the copying order. Problem is, I have a folder structure like this `releases/v1,v2,v3` . folders will be created for each new release. and names of the files will be similar in these folders. and it is required to copy the latest release in to a folder called 'latest' in this scenario it will be required to copy  v3 into 'latest'. so my logic is to copy one by one into 'latest' folder and override the files and the latest file will be remained at the end. my code is like this.

```
 <copy todir="${srcdist.layout.dir}/etc/wsdl/latest"  flatten="true" overwrite="true">
 <fileset dir="../../releases">             
 <include name="**/*.wsdl"/>        
 </fileset>
 </copy>
```

This code works fine for me (in centOS). it starts copying from v1 and ends in v3. but i feel doubt on this copying order whether this will work every time or not. is copy todir sorting the folder names before copying ? please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not good to rely on how `<fileset>` orders the files when copying. So maybe it's better if you can try to change this logic to use a [TimestampSelector](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/timestampselector.html) from the [Ant-Contrib project](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net) to select the newest wsdl file and copy only this file, not all the files of all versions. It could be done like:

```
<timestampselector property="latest.modified">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="../../releases">
      <include name="**/*.wsdl" />
    </fileset>
  </path>
</timestampselector>

<copy todir="${srcdist.layout.dir}/etc/wsdl/latest" file="${latest.modified}"/>
```

Or since Ant 1.7.1 you can use a [Last](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#last) to get the latest file. Here you can find an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6155084/4053652).

Comment: thank you for the reply. according to my requirement I cannot sort it according to the modified or created date because these folders might get modified to provide support services to the old users. I need to sort it by folder name. I have modified the code. can you tell me will it be ok  or not ?   <copy todir="${srcdist.layout.dir}/etc/wsdl/latest"  flatten="true" overwrite="true"> <sort>
 <fileset dir="../../releases">             
 <include name="**/*.wsdl"/>        
 </fileset> </sort>
 </copy>

Comment: Yes, then you need sort them, to be sure in order. Your example seems to be good, just change iclud name to previews version, then it will includ all files in subdirectories

Answer (score 2):

From [Path-like Structures](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) in the Ant documentation:

> ...certain resource collection types such as fileset, dirset and files
>   are undefined in terms of order.

So, you cannot depend on a fileset maintaining any order.

Instead, you can resort to using JavaScript to find the "latest" release directory:

```xml
<!-- match directories starting with "v" under the "releases" directory -->
<dirset id="release.dirs" dir="releases" includes="v*"/>
<script language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
    var dirSet = project.getReference( "release.dirs" );
    var ds = dirSet.getDirectoryScanner( project );
    var includes = ds.getIncludedDirectories();
    var greatestVersion = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < includes.length; i++ )
    {
        var dirname = includes[i];
        // chop off the "v" from the front
        var dirVersion = dirname.substr(1);
        greatestVersion = Math.max( greatestVersion, dirVersion );
    }
    project.setProperty( "greatestVersion", greatestVersion );
]]>
</script>
<copy todir="my-out-dir" verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="releases/v${greatestVersion}" includes="**/*.wsdl"/>
</copy>
```

To test the script, I created several `v#` directories under a `releases` directory. Each of those directories has a `*.wsdl` file.

```
$ ls -R releases/
releases/:
v1  v10  v2  v3

releases/v1:
v1.wsdl

releases/v10:
v10.wsdl

releases/v2:
v2.wsdl

releases/v3:
v3.wsdl
```

The output of running the script:

```
run:
     ...
     [copy] Copying releases\v10\v10.wsdl to my-out-dir\v10.wsdl
```

Answer (score 1):

using sort

```
<copy todir="${srcdist.layout.dir}/etc/wsdl/latest"  flatten="true" overwrite="true">
<sort>
 <fileset dir="../../releases">             
 <include name="**/*.wsdl"/>        
 </fileset>
</sort>
 </copy>
```

Comment: This might cause a problem if you get to version 10 because "10" goes between "1" and "2" in ASCII-based sorting. For example: `1, 2, 3, ..., 10, 11` would be sorted `1, 10, 11, 2, 3, ...`.

Comment: @Chad Nouis  .Thanks . Then  how to sort it by the directory  name ? because  i cannot sort it by the modified or created date. because the old versions might get changed by the support people.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I just posted.