# Jenkins Ant pattern to get Latest Modified XLSX file with timestamp

Tags: jenkins, ant, pattern-matching

How to write Ant pattern to get latest modified file with timestamp.

My Files are :

```
Testcases_Results_dd-mm-yyyy_hh_mm_ss.xlsx
Testcases_Results_dd-mm-yyyy_hh_mm_ss.xlsx
Testcases_Results_dd-mm-yyyy_hh_mm_ss.xlsx
```

In Jenkins i've configured in attachment as **/TestResults/Testcases_Results_*.xlsx
but i'm not getting latest file,it is picking all files.

Answer (score 1):

if your latest file has highest `lastmodifieddate` then you can use

```
<last>
    <sort>
        <date xmlns="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.comparators"/>
        <resources>
            <fileset dir="/path/to/files/">
                <include name="Testcases_Results_*" />
            </fileset>
        </resources>
    </sort>
</last>
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154641/copy-newest-file-with-filename-filter-in-ant).

In another way you can define and use `scriptdef` like

```
<scriptdef name="getLatesFile" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="result"/>
    <element name="fileset" type="fileset"/>
    <![CDATA[

    fileset = elements.get("fileset").get(0);
    scanner = fileset.getDirectoryScanner(project);
    scanner.scan();
    files = scanner.getIncludedFiles();

    var latestDate = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    for( j=0; j < files.length; j++) {

        var filename = files[j];
        var dateSuffix = filename.substring("Testcases_Results_".length, filename.indexOf(".xlsx"));
        //dd-mm-yyyy_hh_mm_ss
        var bits = dateSuffix.split(/\D/);
        var date = new Date(bits[2], --bits[1], bits[0], bits[3], bits[4], bits[5]);
        if(date > latestDate) {
            latestDate = date;
            self.project.setProperty( attributes.get("result"), filename );
        }
    }

  ]]>
</scriptdef>

<target name="init">
    <getLatesFile result="latest_file">
        <fileset dir="/path/to/files/">
            <include name="Testcases_Results_*" />
        </fileset>
    </getLatesFile>
    <echo>${latest_file}</echo>
</target>
```